# How to acces a value in a dictionary of tuples swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to access this dictionary of tuples for certain values assigned to the keys. I can't seem to find out how to access the dictionary once I have filled it with data.

this is the dictionary.

```
 var eventAnnotation = [(eventTitle: String,
                      eventLocation: String,
                           eventLat: CLLocationDegrees,
                          eventLong: CLLocationDegrees)]()
```

this is how i am trying to access it.

```
for event in eventAnnotation {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = eventAnnotation.eventTitle
    annotation.subtitle = eventAnnotation.eventLocation
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: eventAnnotation.eventLat, longitude: eventAnnotation.eventLong)
    eventMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

sorry if this is simple!

Comment: this is not a dictionary. It is an array of tuples. So you have to access it by index or by searching it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var eventAnnotation = [(eventTitle: String,
                     eventLocation: String,
                          eventLat: CLLocationDegrees,
                         eventLong: CLLocationDegrees)]()
```

Above is *not* a dictionary, but an Array of tuples, but *yes*, it is one of the way and you seems to be doing it correctly this way, other ways to loop through an array:

1) using `Array.forEach`

```
eventAnnotation.forEach { event in
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = event.eventTitle
    annotation.subtitle = event.eventLocation
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: event.eventLat, longitude: event.eventLong)
    eventMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

2) Using `Array.map`

```
let annotations: [MKAnnotation] = eventAnnotation.map { event in
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = event.eventTitle
    annotation.subtitle = event.eventLocation
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: event.eventLat, longitude: event.eventLong)
    annotation)
    return annotation
}
eventMap.addAnnotations(annotations)
```

etc...

If you are looking for an **dictionary**, here is how you do the same with dictionary:

```
// Initialize an empty dictionary
var dict: [String : (eventTitle: String, eventLocation: String, eventLat: CLLocationDegrees, eventLong: CLLocationDegrees)] = [:]

// Add an item to dictionary
dict["EventId-1"] = ("Event Title 1", "Event Location 1", 53.0, 27.0)

// Add another item to dictionary
dict["EventId-2"] = (eventTitle: "Event Title 2",
                     eventLocation: "Event Location",
                     eventLat: 53.0,
                     eventLong: 27.0)
```

Here is how you iterate through a dictionary:

```
for (key, event) in dict {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = event.eventTitle
    annotation.subtitle = event.eventLocation
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: event.eventLat, longitude: event.eventLong)
    eventMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

**Update-1** Here is how you filter dictionary for certain keys:

1) Iterate through whole dictionary and search for desired keys:

```
for (key, event) in dict {
    guard (key == "Event1" || key == "Event2") else { continue }

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = event.eventTitle
    annotation.subtitle = event.eventLocation
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: event.eventLat, longitude: event.eventLong)
    eventMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

2) Check if certain key exist in dictionary:

```
if let event = dict["Event1"] {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = event.eventTitle
    annotation.subtitle = event.eventLocation
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: event.eventLat, longitude: event.eventLong)
    eventMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Comment: hello Aamir, thanks for this quick response. I keep getting this error ' Value of type '[(eventTitle: String, eventLocation: String, eventLat: CLLocationDegrees, eventLong: CLLocationDegrees)]' (aka 'Array<(eventTitle: String, eventLocation: String, eventLat: Double, eventLong: Double)>') has no member 'eventTitle' ' any ideas??

Comment: I posted several examples, which one are you using? or just edit your question and add additional code where you having error

Comment: i am using 'array.ForEach' i get the above error for the line of code -  annotation.title = event.eventTitle

Comment: If you are searching for certain keys, check my example `var dict:` and **Update-1** above

Comment: It doesn't seem to loop through or add any annoations using array.foreach example..i must be doing something wrong

Comment: FIXED IT!!! i was calling add the annotations before the array had been filled from firebase. THANK YOU!!!